# Monodevelop 5 does not open javascript files

Tags: javascript, monodevelop, linux-mint

Monodevelop 5.10 does not open javascript files. Neither searches in javascript files.
If I set monodevelop as the default application for js files, monodevelop opens it but as a binary file (unreadable).

I don't really know if this is an operation system issue (Linux Mint 18) or monodevelop's.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try installing the TypeScript add-in